# Connecting Two Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

When I try to connect two forms, I successfully connect them, but the problem is that when I open Form2 from Form1 then Form2 opens but Form2 does not show its buttons, text etc.

I used [these instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws1btzy8(v=vs.90).aspx).

I am using Visual Studio 2012. I believe Visual Studio is doing this mistakenly and I might have to install new visual studio.

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Login_Form
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Form2 frm = new Form2();
      frm.Show();
    }

    // Create Form2.
    public class Form2 : Form
    {
      public Form2()
      {
        Text = "Form2";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Form2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Login_Form
{
  public partial class Form2 : Form
  {
    public Form2()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your Form2 class's constructor contain code like InitializeComponent(); ?

Comment: Again, show your code please.

Comment: Yes it contains InitializeComponent(); @Bahrom

Comment: Maybe you set Visible property of added controls to false. Anyway I believe its not VS's mistake.

Comment: Visible property of all controls is true, i checked it. @Bahrom

Comment: @Trey code is added...

Comment: why do you have a second implementation of the `Form2` class ?

Answer (score 1):

Now remove following code snippet from Form1 class

```
 // Create Form2.  
    public class Form2 : Form  
    {  
        public Form2()  
        {  
            Text = "Form2";  
}  
}
```

Comment: The compiler wont let you do this in Form1 `public class Form2 : Form` because it is NOT a partial class, only in Form2 is it partial...